# React Native iOS, foreground notification not working

Tags: java, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for FCM, when app running in background notification popup shown properly. But when app is running in foreground no notification shown. Same code working for android. Using below code

```
this.firebase.messaging().createLocalNotification({

       title: 'Messenger',     
        body: "message",
        icon: 'ic_launcher',
        id: new Date().getTime()+"",
        action: action,
        screen: screen,
        local_notification: true,
        show_in_foreground: true,
        _notificationType: 'local_notification',
        opened_from_tray: false

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

As from react-native-fcm module the payload must contains following key value pairs.

```
{
        id: "UNIQ_ID_STRING",                               // (optional for instant notification)
        title: "My Notification Title",                     // as FCM payload
        body: "My Notification Message",                    // as FCM payload (required)
        sound: "default",                                   // as FCM payload
        priority: "high",                                   // as FCM payload
        click_action: "ACTION",                             // as FCM payload
        badge: 10,                                          // as FCM payload IOS only, set 0 to clear badges
        number: 10,                                         // Android only
        ticker: "My Notification Ticker",                   // Android only
        auto_cancel: true,                                  // Android only (default true)
        large_icon: "ic_launcher",                           // Android only
        icon: "ic_launcher",                                // as FCM payload, you can relace this with custom icon you put in mipmap
        big_text: "Show when notification is expanded",     // Android only
        sub_text: "This is a subText",                      // Android only
        color: "red",                                       // Android only
        vibrate: 300,                                       // Android only default: 300, no vibration if you pass 0
        group: "group",                                     // Android only
        picture: "https://google.png",                      // Android only bigPicture style
        ongoing: true,                                      // Android only
        my_custom_data:'my_custom_field_value',             // extra data you want to throw
        lights: true,                                       // Android only, LED blinking (default false)
        show_in_foreground                                  // notification when app is in foreground (local & remote)
    }
```

"show_in_foreground" must be provided as to show local notification in foreground when your app is running.

Comment: Yes it should be set to true.

Comment: its set to true only but notification not shown in foreground

Comment: did you impelment  this method in you AppDelafate.m file       ``` -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}```

Comment: Yes already there.  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

Comment: Try this key values in notification payload.

content_available:true,
show_in_foreground:true,
priority:"high"

Comment: Tried no notification. In console I can see payload

Comment: I had used react-native-fcm for push notifications, in which also provides localnotification as u requied.